# Bad file descriptor error when using "x-termial-emulaor -e" for executing child process - C Language

Tags: c, pipe, fork, file-descriptor, execvp

I am trying to run the child processes (S and H) on different shells, the processes need to be able to communicate in both directions, for this i used two unamed pipes.
When I use "x-terminal-emulator -e" to run them, the child processes return the same error in write and select: "Bad File Descriptor", which didn't happen if I ran them on the same shell.

(READ_END = 0, WRITE_END = 1)

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "robot.h"

int spawn_s(int read, int write, bool external);
int spawn_h(int read, int write, bool external);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pids[2]; //process
    int s_h[2]; 
    int h_s[2];

    if (pipe(s_h) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error opening pipe");
        return 1;
    }
    if (pipe(h_s) < 0)
    {
        perror("Error opening pipe");
        return 1;
    }

    
    pids[0] = spawn_s(h_s[READ_END], s_h[WRITE_END], true);
    pids[1] = spawn_h(s_h[READ_END], h_s[WRITE_END], true);
}

int spawn_s(int read, int write, bool external)
{
    pid_t child_pid = fork();
    if (child_pid != 0)
        return child_pid; /* This is the parent process.  */
    else
    {

        char p1[16], p2[16];
        sprintf(p1, "%d", read);
        sprintf(p2, "%d", write);

        char *args[] = {"./s", p1, p2, (char *)NULL};
        char *args_e[] = {"x-terminal-emulator", "-e", "./s", p1, p2, (char *)NULL};
        if (external)
            execvp(args_e[0], args_e);
        else
            execvp(args[0], args);

        fprintf(stderr, "An error occurred in execvp\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
int spawn_h(int read, int write, bool external)
{
    pid_t child_pid = fork();
    if (child_pid != 0)
        return child_pid; /* This is the parent process.  */
    else
    {
        char p1[16], p2[16];
        sprintf(p1, "%d", read);
        sprintf(p2, "%d", write);

        char *args[] = {"./h", p1, p2, (char *)NULL};
        char *args_e[] = {"x-terminal-emulator", "-e", "./h", p1, p2, (char *)NULL};

        if (external)
            execvp(args_e[0], args_e);
        else
            execvp(args[0], args);

        fprintf(stderr, "An error occurred in execvp\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

Is there anything I need to set up before running them on different shells?

Comment: Why do you expect `x-terminal-emulator` to pass all of its FDs to its children?

Comment: I am new to C programming, for my limited knowledge I thought it was enough to pass the fds as an argument (without `x-terminator-emulator` it works). It does not work like this? How can i get what I wrote in the question?